# Does anyone know the name of this novel with 3 anthology stories?

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I believe it had 3 anthology stories that were loosely connected. I know one of them was about a male vampire and female human who fall in love. The vampire needs permission before it can enter her house. But the one in this anthology I really want to reread and find I remember more clearly.

It's about this human woman who is pretty bad ass. I believe a troll killed her family or something like that. She's part of a group that hunts and kills trolls for information. She's looking for a specific troll. When they successfully capture this male troll and chain him up in a basement of sorts, the woman says she will keep watch on him. She asks him questions she wants answers too and he tries to trick her into letting him escape. I think he puts a trance on her? Or maybe they make a deal where she frees him? Anyway, he escapes and the group has to go catch him again.

Later on, the troll turns into stone in the sunlight through a window. By this time, the human woman and male troll have fallen in love.

I can't really remember much else. But I have this feeling that the trolls name started with a T.

Anyone recognize this rough summary? If so, what is the title and name of the author? I believe I read this series some time around 2009 but I don't know when it was published. The book had something like 600 pages, give or take.